# i am facing an issue with checkbox in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.4 when i use input type as checkbox it works in Firefox but it is not working in chrome. The problem comes with when i use it in a table it is not showing up. but outside of table it is showing.

`<td><input type="checkbox" ></td>` if use it in a table it is not showing rest it is working fine. Can anyone help me in solving this issue.

Comment: inspect element and check whether it is there or not, if yes then try by changing css

Comment: Check your CSS in firebug, you might wrote a CSS rule that whatever comes in td will be hidden

Comment: No the problem for me is that checkbox is not visible only in chrome, opera browsers, when i declare it a table

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this :**

**E.g.**

```
 {{ Form::checkbox('agree', 'yes') }}
```

**Reference :** http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/167/creating-a-checkbox-input-field

Comment: Form isn't included in laravel 5.x, you need to install it separately. Laravel itself not supporting the Form component as it will increase the rendering slow

Comment: can you help me with any other method

Comment: @naveen Please provide your link if possible.